# Collapse e nem dropdown funciona?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap, collapse

O que tem de errado no seguinte código, `collapse` e nem `dropdown` funciona.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

<title> </title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
</script>


</head>

<body class="text-center">
<form class="form-signin bg-white rounded box-shadow">
  <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">


  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Usuário</label>
  <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>

  <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Idade</label>
  <input type="date" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name="bday" max="1979-12-31"required autofocus>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Right-aligned menu
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
      </div>
    </div> 


  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Estado</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Country" required>

  <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Cidade</label>
  <input type="text" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="City/UF" required>

  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Registrar-se</button>
  <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo o que está acontecendo é que a ordem que vc chama os scripts está errada

Repare que primeiro deve vir os CDNs (links com os .js que vc vai precisar) e depois deve vir seu `<script>` pois ele depende dos CDNs para funcionar. Veja abaixo para entender.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
    </script>
```

**As regras são as mesmas para o Bootstrap3.** *Na verdade qualquer `<script>` que vc usar que use jQuery por exemplo deve sempre vir abaixo da indexação do jQuery*

***Outro Exemplo:***

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
</script>
```

> Veja o código completo funcionando no no Snipper abaixo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
    
</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <form class="form-signin bg-white rounded box-shadow">
        <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
      
      
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Usuário</label>
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
      
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Idade</label>
        <input type="date" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" name="bday" max="1979-12-31"required autofocus>
      
          <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Right-aligned menu
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
              <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
              <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
            </div>
          </div> 
      
      
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Estado</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Country" required>
      
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Cidade</label>
        <input type="text" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="City/UF" required>
      
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Registrar-se</button>
        <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2017-2018</p>
      </form>
    


    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```